# useEffect not triggered on state update by its dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to implement a seamless login and trigger another function when login is successful

```
const [token, setToken] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    async function attemptLogin() {
      await fetch('http://localhost:3000/login')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data.data))
        .then(data => setToken(JSON.stringify(data))) // {data: 'Logged in'}
        .catch(err => {
          console.error('error occured: ', err.message)
        });
    }
    attemptLogin();
  }, []);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('should run after token update');
  console.log(token); //undefined
  // another fetch goes here since we needed to login to get token for API 
}, [token]);
```

So the `useEffect` with the dependency runs before the one used on mounting. why? Shouldn't it run only when state changes? Does it run on initialization or something? Then why not run when I get the data from my fetch?

Comment: Looking at your code the useEffect with dependency might run before. But does it not run after the token has updated too?

Comment: nope, that is what confuses me

Comment: Seems that this is not correct. `.then(data => console.log(data.data))
        .then(data => setToken(JSON.stringify(data))) ` . It should be `.then(data => { console.log(data.data);  setToken(JSON.stringify(data)); })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this piece of code:

```
       .then(data => console.log(data.data))
        .then(data => setToken(JSON.stringify(data)))
```

In `.then()`, data is not passed on further to the next `.then()`. That is why the second `.then()` becomes something like `setToken(JSON.stringify(undefined))`.

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(undefined))
```

As you see that will return `undefined` so you are doing `setToken(undefined)`.

You probably want to do `.then(data => data.data)` instead of `.then(data => console.log(data.data))`, so you are actually returning something.

**Note:** Do not need the second `.then()` because there is nothing async here :

```
.then(data => setToken(JSON.stringify(data.data)))
```

Also,

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('should run after token update');
  console.log(token); //undefined
  // another fetch goes here since we needed to login to get token for API 
}, [token]);
```

the callback in this `useEffect` will run on the first render (mount) because `token` is given a value at that time (although `undefined`). This counts as a change for React, because earlier the variable did not even exist [(a codesandbox demonstrating this)](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-architecture-yq6eek?file=/src/App.js:0-337).

From the docs:

> Does useEffect run after every render? Yes! By default, it runs both after the first render and after every update.

You can check for the first mount using a `ref` if you do not want this to run on first mount or check the value for `undefined` using `if`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I used an if to check `token` value and prevent unwanted behavior from the useEffect with dependency

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```js
async function attemptLogin() {
      let res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/login')
      let jsonData = await res.json();
      setToken(jsonData)
    }
```

Comment: That.. actually triggered the useEffect with the dependency, I added an if statement to check if the token is undefined, so it runs when data is there. 

Can you elaborate on why your snippet works?

Comment: most of the times , using `async/await` syntax reduces unintentional errors and it is much easier that `.then()`